# Attach file from web page directly into an Outlook email

Tags: email, web-applications, web, outlook, email-attachments

I have a web app that generates pdf reports. Currently users can send this generated report to email addresses from within the web app.  The recipient email addresses receive an email with the pdf as an attachment.

However, now the users have requested the ability to drag the generated pdf report from within the web app directly into an outlook email, similarly to when you drag a file from windows explorer into an email. It will then add the file to the email as an attachment and they can send it to whoever they like. Is this possible?

If drag and drop is not possible is there any other way at all that a user can attach a file to outlook directly from a webpage?